# How to style Plotly depending on site's color scheme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, plotly

I am working on a website using Material-UI React framework and we are making use of its theming capabilities to let the user dynamically change the appearance. Is there a way to easily set default colors for the text Plotly renders, so it contrasts nicely with the site's background?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this for the moment:

```
import React from 'react';
import PlotlyPlot from 'react-plotly.js';
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core';
import { merge } from '../lodash.custom';

const Plot = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const layout = merge({
    paper_bgcolor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    plot_bgcolor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    xaxis: {
      color: theme.palette.text.primary
    },
    yaxis: {
      color: theme.palette.text.primary
    },
    legend: {
      font: {
        color: theme.palette.text.primary
      },
    },
    title: {
      font: {
        color: theme.palette.text.primary,
      }
    },
    scene: {
      xaxis: {
        color: theme.palette.text.primary
      },
      yaxis: {
        color: theme.palette.text.primary
      },
      zaxis: {
        color: theme.palette.text.primary
      },
    }
  }, props.layout);
  const data = props.data.map(plotData => merge({
    colorbar: {
      tickfont: {
        color: theme.palette.text.primary
      }
    }
  }, plotData));
  const customProps = {
    layout,
    data
  };
  return <PlotlyPlot ref={ref} {...customProps} />;
});
```